# Happend multiple .csv file from Drive Folder to Unique Sheet in Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello to everyone guys!

I've got a problem with the code below; my purpose is to retrieve all the .csv file in a google drive folder and put them all in sequence in a specific sheet in Google.

The error code that it get is: "Exception: Cannot convert 'function () { [native code] }1' to int."

Could you please help me solving that issue?

Many thanks in advance

```
function happendCSV() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID_Folder");
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name");
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    //let fn = file.getName();
    let fileID = file.getId();
    let fileType = file.getMimeType();
    if (fileType === "text/csv") {
      let csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");
      sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow +1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `sheet.getLastRow`  of `sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow +1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);` should be `sheet.getLastRow()`. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `Exception: Cannot convert 'function () { [native code] }1' to int.`.
- In your situation, I thought that `getFilesByType` might be useful.
- When `setValues` is used outside of the loop, the process cost becomes low a little.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function happendCSV() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID_Folder");
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name");
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);
  let values = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");
    values = [...values, ...csvData];
    console.log(`Now: ${file.getName()}`); // For confirming the current processing file.
  }
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- If your CSV data is large, Sheets API might be suitable instead of Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp).

#### References:

- [getFilesByType(mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbytypemimetype)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Comment: Thank you man, now everything is working as I wish, you've been great!

To understand better your note: what does it means large? How many rows for example?

Comment: @Amidaraxar Thank you for replying. About `Thank you man, now everything is working as I wish, you've been great!`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `To understand better your note: what does it means large? How many rows for example?`, I apologize for my poor English skill. `large` is the number of cells in `values` (The number of rows is also related to this.). In this case, my report might help understand it. https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4

Comment: @Amidaraxar By the way, if your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thank you again. I've accepted the solution and now I'm gonna read your report.
Just a single last question: how can I modify the code to be able to happend the other .csv file (starting from the second one of course) without the first row that contains the header with general information?

Comment: @Amidaraxar Thank you for your response. About `Just a single last question: how can I modify the code to be able to happend the other .csv file (starting from the second one of course) without the first row that contains the header with general information?`, in this case, how about modifying `let csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");` to `let [,...csvData] = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");`? By this, the 1st row of the CSV data is skipped. If I misunderstood it, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

```
function happendCSV() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID_Folder");
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    //let fn = file.getName();
    let fileID = file.getId();
    let csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
}function happendCSV() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID_Folder");
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let fileID = file.getId();
    let csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
}
```